# Where can I find Siri's file, folders, database in ios files (I'm root)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, siri, root

I would like to modify some things on the OS including the 'Hey Siri' phrase, I've tried a global grep but no luck yet.

If someone has an idea, he is welcome

Comment: A total guess would be that it's in a binary file somewhere that you'd need to take apart and put back together to change.

Comment: Mmh that sounds impossible, but someone managed to fo it a few weeks ago, I'm sure it must be somewhere :)

Comment: Do you consider this question to be unanswered/unresolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not just some file you can just go edit for the "Hey, Siri..." phrase. There are localized language files for Assistant (Siri) and the rest of iOS that contain information about what certain words and language in general looks like to a computer. I'm fairly certain that these files are located at `/System/Library/LinguisticData/`. There are people who have modified the "Hey, Siri..." phrase before, so it's not impossible, but it's not just a simple edit of some `.plist` somewhere.